How to calculate the percentage of change on rows with NA
How do I find and calculate the percentage of change of an indicator throughout time when there are several NAs spread throughout the data?
Let's assume that this is my dataframe:
     a   b   c   d   e
07  10  NA  NA   8   7
06   8  NA   5  NA   8
05  11  NA   7   6   7
04   5  NA   6   5   9
03  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
02  NA  NA  NA   3  12
01  NA  NA  10  NA  15

Knowing that each row represents data from a certain year, I want to find the percentage of difference between the lowest row (earliest row) that contains a non-NA number and the uppermost row  (latest row) that contains a non-NA number.
The result should look like this:
 a     b     c     d     e
 1    NA    -1  1.66 -0.53

The code should be easily replicated since I have hundreds of rows to analyse (eg: it shouldn't involve manually adding each column or row name).
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

You should show the logic that arrives at that result from that data. Your description seems quite vague.

Welcome to all SO! Your questions so far seem to be asking people to write code for you. This site works best when you show us what you’ve attempted and we can help you troubleshoot from there. But this is not a code writing service. Without attempted code, you may attract some unwanted negative attention. Just trying to look out for you and ensure you have a good experience with this site. Good luck!

First finding the non-NAs, then checking if any column had all NAs with length, finally do the calculation with lowest and highest indices.
sapply(df, \(x){ 
  w_case <- which(!is.na(x))
  ifelse(length(w_case) > 0, 
         (x[min(w_case)] - x[max(w_case)]) / x[max(w_case)], 
         NA)})
         a          b          c          d          e 
 1.0000000         NA -0.5000000  1.6666667 -0.5333333

Data
df <- structure(list(a = c(10L, 8L, 11L, 5L, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c = c(NA, 5L, 7L, 6L, NA, NA, 10L), 
    d = c(8L, NA, 6L, 5L, NA, 3L, NA), e = c(7L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 
    NA, 12L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("07", 
"06", "05", "04", "03", "02", "01"))


Some improvements you might consider: vapply(df, \(x) { w = which(!is.na(x)); if (length(w)) (x[min(w)] - x[i <- max(w)]) / x[i] else NA }, numeric(1L))
